# Spring Boot JPA : Autowired JPA repository extends CrudRepository is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am not getting repository bean in service class.

[image: project code]

Comment: please post your code, not images,... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your interface `ActorRepository` must be annotated with `@Repository`.